# Static inheritance python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make some kind of static inheritance happen.
The code below prints "nope".
I'm not sure how to explain myself but what I want is that
class A uses B's method if it exists.

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test():
       print("nope")

    @staticmethod
    def test2():
        __class__.test()

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        print("It Works")

    @staticmethod
    def run():
        __class__.test2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B.run()
```

Comment: Then don't use static methods. Use class methods instead.

Comment: If you are looking for *static* inheritance, chances are high that you are doing something wrong…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__class__` as a closure reference was never meant to be used as a reference to the current *instance* type; it'll always refer to the class you defined a method on (e.g. `A` for `A.test2`). It is a internal implementation detail used by the `super()` function. Don't use it here.

Use [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) instead;

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
       print("nope")

    @classmethod
    def test2(cls):
        cls.test()

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print("It Works")

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        cls.test2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B.run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love this site!